# Python logging.SMTP handler is not working

Tags: python, email, logging, handler, smtplib

What I am trying to do is create a separate logger that will send error logs via email.
However, every time I call the  *email_logger.error('...')*, the following error occurs:

> smtplib.SMTPNotSupportedError: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.

The code I am using is displayed bellow:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s :: %(funcName)s :: %(levelname)s :: %(message)s')

email_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
email_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) as server:
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()
    server.login('host_email@gmail.com', r'thisismypassword')
    smtp_handler = logging.handlers.SMTPHandler(mailhost=('smtp.gmail.com', 587),
                                                fromaddr='host_email@gmail.com',
                                                toaddrs=['mymail@gmail.com'],
                                                subject='A dashing subject',
                                                credentials=('host_email@gmail.com',
                                                             r'thisismypassword'),
                                                secure=None)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s : %(funcName)s : %(levelname)s : %(name)s : %(message)s')
    smtp_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    email_logger.addHandler(smtp_handler)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the same issue while sending emails through the logging module to an Amazon STMP server (Amazon SES). I solved this by using `secure=()`.

Because when sending an email to an STMP that imposes the secure mode, the `secure` option must not be `None`. This is the code use internally by the logging module to send email:

```py
            if self.username:
                if self.secure is not None:
                    smtp.ehlo()
                    smtp.starttls(*self.secure)
                    smtp.ehlo()
                smtp.login(self.username, self.password)
            smtp.send_message(msg)
            smtp.quit()
```

Thus, to use the secure mode without passing parameters to `smtp.starttls`, I set the secure option to `()` and it solved my issue: it properly uses a TLS connection to send email to the SMTP server.

Answer (score 0):

When I use Gmail for sending emails from Python I use:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
```

Also, try connecting to the server just in a regular python shell

```
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) 
server.login(username, password)
```

to see if your details are correct, it maybe you need to set up an app password to use Gmail from an application, depending on your security settings